# Terrain data for Germany

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Hello experienced people!!
Being a student, I am in need of free of cost terrain data of Germany which is accurate too.
Actually my Task is to get terrain data for smaller size like a plot for a building anywhere in Germany and plotting that terrain in Autodesk Revit. My Ist priority is to to Use Autodesk Revit only but in between software like QGIS and Civil 3D could also be used for terrain modeling and then bringing that terrain to Revit.

Comment: If by "terrain" you synonymously mean "elevation" data, there are several OD posts with answers and comments suggesting potential sources covering your use case: [one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9689/7031), [two](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/195/7031), [three](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6542/7031), [four](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3288/7031)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the spatial resolution you need ("accurate" isn't very precise :-) ), and perhaps the purpose in more detail since the indicated software isn't known to all of us.

Comment: Would terrain tiles work in Autodesk Revit ?

Comment: yes . i will work in Autodesk Revit